# how to make plugins of tinyMCE in react js?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I am using `react js`. I am using `tinyMCE` editor to take to write the article. Now I learn the term of plugins in tinyMCE. I read the documentation but all the documentation is for `PHP`. I haven't find any documentation to make the `plugins` of `tinyMCE` in `react`. kindly give me some breif information and example to make the plugins of `tinyMCE editor` in react js app`.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE plugins are JavaScript files (not PHP) that are loaded by the core TinyMCE editor itself when the editor is initialized.

While the files are JavaScript they are not (and cannot be) React components.

We have documentation that outlines how to create a plugin:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/creating-a-plugin/

You can also look at any of the existing open source plugins for examples of how to create your own plugin.  All of the open source plugins include unminified code that you can review to see how they are built.